# JavaFX: setStrokeType() make my program extremely slow

Tags: java, javafx

I just start to use JavaFX and the `setStrokeType()` function seems to make my program running extremely slow, and sometimes it even crashes.

Once I put `-fx-stroke-type:outside;` in my CSS file and use it, or use `label_4.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);` my program will run slowly, I can't even click a checkbox.

Here it's my code:

```
#label{ 
    -fx-font:25 Arial;
    -fx-font-weight:900;
    -fx-fill: white;
    -fx-stroke: #989898;
    -fx-stroke-width: 1;
    -fx-stroke-type:outside;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.45), 2, 0, 0, 1);
}



public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
         StackPane root = new StackPane();
         Scene scene = new Scene(root, 856, 290);
         primaryStage.setResizable(false);
         root.setId("pane");
         scene.getStylesheets().add("./application/application.css");
         CheckBox check_1 = new CheckBox("Check two");
         check_1.getStyleClass().add("check");
         CheckBox check_2 = new CheckBox("Check one");
         check_2.getStyleClass().add("check");

         Text t= new Text("TEST TEST TEST TEST");
         t.setId("label");
         root.getChildren().addAll(check_1,check_2,t);

         primaryStage.setTitle("Hello world");
         primaryStage.setScene(scene);
         primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try 
        { 
            launch(args);
         } 
         catch (Exception e) 
         { 
            System.out.println(e.toString()); 
         } 
     } 
 }
```

Comment: What are you using to profile the code? What environment runs the code?

Comment: BUG: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089081

Answer (score 2):

I think you are dealing with a bug here. Your code runs with responsive problems as you mention.

I've made some tests with Scene Builder 2.0:

```
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
        <Text fill="WHITE" layoutX="119.0" layoutY="192.0" stroke="#989898" strokeType="OUTSIDE" text="TEST TEST TEST TEST">
           <font>
              <Font name="Arial Bold" size="36.0" />
           </font>
           <effect>
              <DropShadow color="#00000072" offsetY="1.0" />
           </effect>
        </Text>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

This uses 100 MB of memory and I can move the slider of the font size flawlessly.

However, if I set the stroke type to `OUTSIDE` or `INSIDE`, Scene Builder requires 125 MB of memory, and the font size slider becomes irresponsive (memory jumps to 175 MB, and cpu goes to 100% of one core).

[image: Stroke problems]

Please consider filing a bug [report](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa).

Comment: Hey Jose, thank u so much for reply, I'm using Eclipse Luna on Win 7. I don't down how they tested the function when they publish it. For now it doesn't work for me, I'll try to do a bug report to see how they response. Cheers :-)