# Javafx - textflow + text = very slow

Tags: java, javafx

I'm running a textflow in javafx with a lot of text fields inside of it.
All told it's about 500 lines and ~20.000 text items.

The textflow itself is in a scrollpane so only partially visible. Scrolling is "ok" but any layout() action takes ages. Is there a way to limit textflow layout to the visible part? Or to speed it up in another way?

Comment: The speed of my code when rendering `Text` with things like: `text.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 0, 128, 0.5));` / `text.setEffect(dropShadow);` / `text.setStroke(Color.rgb(0, 0, 128));` are fine. \
But once **`text.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);`** is used, it becomes very slow (especially when Text is long). Idk why. \ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613987/javafx-setstroketype-make-my-program-extremely-slow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that on layout() the system has to layout even invisible items. You need to use a VirtualFlow control like ListView to make the system only hold the nodes visible on screen!

There are various controls from the community out there to support rendering big amounts of text. See https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX/wiki/JavaFX-Controls-for-Code-Editing